# NHibernate updated timestamp property in entity after update

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have an ASP.NET / SQL Server application that utilizes NHibernate. I am a newbie to NHibernate and I am having issues with concurrency.

The sktAllocations table has a `TS_tblAllocations` column that is of a `Timestamp` type. When I perform an update on the `sktAllocations` table the `TS_tblAllocations` property in the entity is not updated. Is there anyway to tell NHibernate to update the `TS_tblAllocations` field after an update within the mapping code? Or do I need to manually get the whole entity from the database after an update?

Below is the important parts of the NHibernating XML mapping for `sktAllocations`.

```
<hibernate-mapping assembly="Trauma.Core" 
     namespace="Trauma.Core.Domain.Model" xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="Sktallocations" table="sktAllocations" lazy="true" >
    <id name="Fallocationid" column="FAllocationID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    .
    .
    .
    <property name="TS_tblAllocations" generated="always">
      <column name="TS_tblAllocations" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
    </property>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: Witch version of Nhibernate are you using? what is the type of the column on sql server? you can have a look here about some info hoe to map time values to nhibernate http://jameskovacs.com/2011/01/26/datetime-support-in-nhibernate/

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: NHibernate Version 2.2 and the column type is a timestamp

Answer (score 1):

I am using the same feature with SQL Server `timestamp`. With NHibernate 4+ *(the same with 3.3.+)* and mapping like this - All is working as expected, after any  **UPDATE there is immediate SELECT of that column**:

```
<class name="Sktallocations" table="sktAllocations" lazy="true"
    optimistic-lock="version" dynamic-update="true" batch-size="25" >

    <id name="Fallocationid" column="FAllocationID">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    .
    .
    .

    // <property name="TS_tblAllocations" generated="always">
    //  <column name="TS_tblAllocations" sql-type="timestamp" not-null="false" />
    // </property>


    <version name="TS_tblAllocations" generated="always" 
             unsaved-value="null" type="BinaryBlob">
      <column name="TS_tblAllocations" not-null="false" sql-type="timestamp"/>
    </version>

</class>
```

And property like this

```
public class Sktallocations
{
    ...
    protected virtual byte[] TS_tblAllocations { get; set; }
```

Check doc:

- [5.1.7. version (optional)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-version)

And maybe also

- [5.1.8. timestamp (optional)](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-timestamp)

Comment: The following error message is displayed after adding the version element to the Nhibernate xml mapping file. Trauma.Core.Domain.Model.Sktallocations.hbm.xml(34,6): XML validation error: The element 'class' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2' has invalid child element 'version' in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'. List of possible elements expected: 'property, many-to-one, one-to-one, component, dynamic-component, properties, any, map, set, list, bag, idbag, array, primitive-array, join, subclass, joined-subclass, ... in namespace 'urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2'.

Comment: Great to see that progress... why? because you are almost there! ;) the `<version>` should be the first element after `<id>` declaration. No `<property` or `<many-to-one`... Just the first after ID and then all will work ;) Enjoy NHibernate

Comment: Included links are 404